# DataWizExt Shading stopped working in Safari

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have been using DataViz Extensions for a while. Shading suddenly stopped working in Safari (screenshot is below). Chrome is ok.

Anyone knows why this is happening? My Safari version is 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4). ForgeViewer version 7.46 (what I got for 7.*).

Thanks
Bandu

[image: Safari error in shading]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this. I'm afraid that this is a compatibility problem on the DataViz extension side. I'm able to reproduce the same issue when opening https://hyperion.autodesk.io in Safari (14.1.1). Let me report the problem to the engineering team, and please stay tuned for updates on the [viewer changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7).

Comment: Thanks Bandu/Petr, I'm looking into this right now.

Comment: Bandu, Ben has found and fixed the issue. It will go live with the next release of Forge Viewer which should happen in approx 1 week. Thanks Ben!